# How to access a variable outside setCallback function in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, callback

I know how to set value of a variable outside setCallback function and use it within it.

```
$response = new StreamedResponse();  
$i = 0;  
$params = "hello";
$response->setCallback(function () use ($params){  
    while($i < 999999){  
        echo 'Something';  
        $i = $i + 1;  
    }  
});
```

i.e. by using `use` .
I want to set the value of a variable from within this callback function and want to use it outside the function.  How can I achieve this without using a global variable?

```
$response = new StreamedResponse();  
$i = 0;  
$params = "hello";
$response->setCallback(function () use ($params){
// --- Set variable here ---  
    while($i < 999999){  
      echo 'Something';  
      $i = $i + 1;  
    }  
}); 

 -- Use variable here ---
```

I tried below code but is is not working -

```
$response = new StreamedResponse();

$format = "json";

$response->setCallback(function () use(&$format) {

    $format = "xml"; 
    echo $format; //prints xml

});

echo $format; //prints json
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a variable by reference in the `use` statement by using the `&` operator:

```
<?php

$foo = 0;

$closure = function() use (&$foo) {
    $foo = 5;
};

$closure();

echo "$foo"; // will output "5"
```

Comment: Thanks. How should I pass the variable if I am passing an array of parameters instead of single variable?

Comment: If you have more than one argument you have to prefix each one with an ampersand: `... use (&$one, &$two, &$three)`. Whether or not one of the arguments is an array does not matter, you just use it like a “normal“ variable.

Comment: Your code is working fine but this technique is not working for me. I am trying to set value of a variable in setCallback() function of StreamedResponse. Please confirm. edited the question.

Comment: The callback will only be executed when the response is sent to the client (i.e. `$response->send()` is called.) This is done by the framework itself *after* the controller has finished. If you’re using the full-stack Symfony framework you can’t (shouldn’t) do that yourself. The only two options I can see are a) move the code that uses the response *inside* the closure or b) don’t use `StreamedResponse` but a normal `Response` instead.

Comment: I also figured out the same. So restructured the code. Thanks